# How to import models in google colab which is saved in a folder?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I saved my resnet50 model in a folder named 'models'. While using jupyter notebooks in my device, I used to simply import using 'import models'. I have uploaded the models folder in google drive. But this command is not working in google colab. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by following these steps:

1. make a folder named models in '/content'
2. move every file from the G-drive using the following code:
   !mv 'file_name' 'dest_folder'

I got help from a friend and this was the best we could come up with. Hope this helps other users!